# Handling 'joinGroup' and 'sendToGroup' events in Azure PubSub with Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions, azure-pubsub

I have an Azure PubSub service with an event handler configured using Azure Functions.

[image: Image showing event handler configuration in Azure with connect, connected and disconnected system events, and all user events enabled]

With a basic web socket connection from a React app I can connect, send messages, and trigger events in Azure Functions.

Client side JS:

```
const ws = new WebSocket("http://myservice.azure.com");
    ws.onopen = () => {
      ws.send("message");
    };
```

Azure Functions:

```
[FunctionName("NotificationConnected")]
        public static void Connected(
        ILogger logger,
        [WebPubSubTrigger("notification", WebPubSubEventType.System, "connected")] ConnectedEventRequest request,
        BinaryData data,
        WebPubSubDataType dataType)
        {
            logger.LogInformation("Request from: {user}, data: {data}, dataType: {dataType}",
                request.ConnectionContext.UserId, data?.ToString(), dataType);

        }

[FunctionName("NotificationMessage")]
        public static async void NotificationMessage(
        ILogger logger,
        [WebPubSubTrigger("notification", WebPubSubEventType.User, "message")] UserEventRequest request,
        BinaryData data,
        WebPubSubDataType dataType)
        {
            logger.LogInformation("Request from: {user}, data: {data}, dataType: {dataType}",
                request.ConnectionContext.UserId, data.ToString(), dataType);

        }
```

The above all works as expected and both functions fire. I want to enable group level messaging using the `json.webpubsub.azure.v1` sub protocol so on the client side I now have:

```
const handleMessage = (message: any) => {
        const container = JSON.parse(message);
        if (container.ackId === 1) {
          ws.send(JSON.stringify({
            "type": "sendToGroup",
            "group": state.group,
            "ackId": ++ackId,
            "dataType": "text",
            "data": "group message"
          }));
        }
      }

    const ws = new WebSocket("http://myservice.azure.com", "json.webpubsub.azure.v1");
    ws.onopen = () => {
      ws.send(JSON.stringify({
        type: 'joinGroup',
        group: state.group,
        ackId: ++ackId
      }));
    };

ws.onmessage = function (e) {
  handleMessage(e.data);
};
```

In Azure PubSub I can see the client connecting to the group and sending messages to the group, and the 'connected' function still fires in Azure Functions but the 'message' function doesn't.

How can I bind to the joinGroup and sendToGroup events now in Azure Functions?

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this? I have the same problem. It seems that if it is a group message (regardless of subprotocol or not) I cannot get an Azure function binding to trigger. Perhaps the only way is the upstream "sendEvent" stuff but that would mean the Azure function would lose reference of what group the message was from.